# Displaying both PNG and JPEG files in React

Tags: reactjs

I think this is a repeat question but I can't seem to find the right answer...

I can upload png and jpeg images just fine (mern with multer) however when it comes to displaying the PNG file I have some issues.

File location is in the public/uploads folder

Successful display of JPEG (Displays JPEG correctly with the following) but fails on PNG

```
<img src={`${post.image}`} alt="testing"></img>
```

Error when it comes to PNG (404 Not Found)

```
GET http://localhost:3000/uploads/postImage-1637006445002-134875838-Screen%20Shot%202021-11-15%20at%205.25.09%20PM.png 404 (Not Found)
```

If I try the following, I get another kind of error for both JPEG and PNG

```
<img src={require(post.image).default} alt="testing"></img>
 Cannot find module '/uploads/postImage-1637006445002-134875838-Screen Shot 2021-11-15 at 5.25.09 PM.png'
```

Doing an import such as below doesn't really make sense since I'm pulling the image name from a database and then referencing it's location in the public/uploads folder

```
import Image from 'uploads/fileName.png';
```

My other option is to a fileFilter on the backend and limit uploads to just JPEG but that seems limiting.

The only difference between the two that I can tell is the file type.  Backend file handling is the exact same, so my question is how do I display PNG images the same exact way that I display JPEG's?  Is there some config with React that I have to change?

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you,

Comment: `My other option is to a fileFilter on the backend and limit uploads to just JPEG but that seems limiting` .How do you have Only option of JPEG and not PNG on backend?

Comment: I don't do any filtering right now so all files are accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Your web server may be setup to `receive` the PNG mime type, but not to `send` files of this type, which would account for the 404 error you are receiving when you try to render it. Each web server is different in [how this is configured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Configuring_server_MIME_types).

Comment: The file does get created and stored in the public/uploads folder, but I'm not sure why React can't pull them in the same way I do JPEG's.  I if I manually reference the file with an import statement, it works, but manually importing a file with an import statement doesn't work if I'm calling images dynamically from a database.  Also, I'm using Reacts built in web server (npm run start)

Comment: Yep, that's odd. Is the name of your jpg image like the name of your png image? Full of spaces and dashes and dots? Not sure why it would make a difference, but maybe sanitizing the filename during save could make a difference. You say you're databasing the filenames, so if you renamed the file on upload (something like a GUID without the dashes)...?

Comment: Haha that was apparently it!  My PNG file did have spaces, once I took them out, it was all good.  It didn't even occur to me.  Thanks for the call out and yeah once I took out the spaces it all worked just like it should.  Thanks for bringing attention to that :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know that spaces in the file name when uploading wouldn't get pulled properly by React.  If you're running into this, what fixed my issue was removing spaces from the filename.  Thanks to [Steve -Cutter- Blades](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63437/steve-cutter-blades) for pointing it out.